# How do I set the production / development environment when running a Sinatra App localy

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, bundler

I have the following in my Gemfile, but when i run bundle install on my local, i get an error about postgres being unavailable.

```
group :development do
  gem 'dm-sqlite-adapter'
end

group :production do
  gem 'dm-postgres-adapter'  
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Bundler to exclude the production group:

```
bundle install --without production
```

It will remember this for future runs on the same machine (it stores this in the `.bundle` directory), so you only need to do this once and then can simply do `bundle` or `bundle install` in the future.